# Is Dharma is equal to Religion?

Tags: dharma, translation-request

This is a bit confusing. Sometimes public use **dharma** in the same sense as the English word **religion**.

But as per Wikipedia entry for **[Dharma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharma)**:

> There is [no single word translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Untranslatability) for *dharma* in western languages.

Is it true?

Comment: Dharma is that which holds everything or one without which everything falls.Religion is no where near a good synonym of Dharma.

Comment: For ex-religions can be many but Dharma is one.